# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Count1'....?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Why is this error coming i could not understand
What is wrong

thats my view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import poll

# Create your views here.
def index(request):

    polls = poll.objects.get()
    
    context ={
         'polls':polls,
     }
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # print(request.POST)

        selected_option = request.POST.get('polls')
        # print(selected_option)

        if selected_option == 'choice1':
            print(selected_option)
            polls.count1 = polls.count1 + 1
        elif selected_option == 'choice2':
            print(selected_option)
            polls.count2 += 1
        elif selected_option == 'choice3':
            print(selected_option)
            polls.count3 += 1

    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    choice1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    choice2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    choice3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    count1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    count2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    count3 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

As we can see count1 is in my models then why does'nt it shows

even when i put it in my html file it also shows there.

What to do next

Comment: It doesn't have a `Count1`, it has a `count1`

Comment: Thanks @Sayse still it dosn't  works]

Comment: Make sure you have corrected all cases where you have written `CountX` instead of `countX`.

Comment: "it dosn't works" is not a description of the issues you're having

Comment: @Sayse still it shows as 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'count1'

Comment: have u updated you model ?

Answer (score 0):

Django and python code is case sensitive, you have Count1 as first letter Uppercase, while in models you use all lowercase properties.